# Can't insert into MongoDB due to AutoReconnect

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Background: 
I've got a python script using pymongo that pulls some XML data, parses it into an array of dictionaries called 'all_orders'. I then try to insert it into the collection "orders" and I invariably get this exception. I am reasonably certain that my array of dictionaries is correct because when the list is small it tends to work (I think). I've also found that 8 out of the ~1300 documents I tried to insert into the collection worked.

Question:
Do you know what causes this AutoReconnect(str(e)) exception? Do you know how to work around or avoid this issue?

Error Trace: 
File "mongovol.py", line 152, in get_reports
    orders.insert(all_orders)
File "/Users/ashutosh/hrksandbox/lumoback-garden2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 359, in insert
    continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
File "/Users/ashutosh/hrksandbox/lumoback-garden2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 853, in _send_message
    raise AutoReconnect(str(e))

Comment: The workaround I'm using currently is to do insert each document in my iterable one at a time instead of doing a bulk insert and letting pymongo handle the inserting each individual record in the iterable.